# How to solve the 2D wave equation given the Helmholtz solutions containing bessel functions?

Tags: polar-coordinates, bessel-functions, wave-equation

I am struggling conceptually with what this question is asking me to do. The question is:

*In polar coordinates the Helmholtz equation has solutions of the form:*

$$u_m=(AJ_m(\sqrt{\lambda}+(BY_m(\sqrt{\lambda}r)(C\cos{m}\phi+D\sin{m}\phi)$$

*where J and Y are bessel functions of the first and second kind. Find solutions to the 2D wave equation that are regular at the origin.*

Now, I am happy with separation of variables of the wave equation, into R(r), $\Phi(\phi)$, and T(t).
I think I am correct in thinking that the helmholtz solutions are for the time independent part of the wave equation, i.e. $u_m=R(r)\times\Phi(\phi)$ ?

Then my question is, can I just multiply the time dependence of the separated wave equation onto the Helmholtz solution, to get a general solution to the 2D wave equation? i.e.:

$$u(r,\phi,t)=T_0e^{\pm i\lambda t}(AJ_m(\sqrt{\lambda}+(BY_m(\sqrt{\lambda}r)(C\cos{m}\phi+D\sin{m}\phi)$$

Feels like I am missing the point.
Thanks,